# How to iterate over the awk result?

Tags: awk

I need to split the path into small pieces. As we know, the path is like the format as `/home/tommy/test`, I really need to split them into `home tommy test`, So can I iterate over the result?

For example, I need to get all of the sub items in `$PWD`.

Comment: Kindly add samples to your post with your efforts to solve the problem too and let us know then.

Comment: I don't know why there're two down vote. I know it's easy to implement when use python or other script, even it's only a one code and I can get the exactly what I want. I'm not familiar with awk and have tried this out on my local without any successful, that's why I post my questions here to ask for help. Very disappointment for the guys who votes down for this question. And also I think my question is very clear just want use awk to split the path into array and I can iterator them. The only reason I think the guys doesn't like my question maybe the title of this question.

Comment: I believe that downvotes are there because the question is ill-posed. You state you want to iterate, but your example actually reads: I want to take all `/` and transform them into whitespaces. Maybe you'd like to [review and edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50849114/edit) your question to better explain what you need.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo $PWD | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "/" } 
{ 
 x=1 
while ( x<=NF ) { 
    print $x " " 
    x++ 
}}'
```

Comment: It seems doesn't work. for example. I ported your code as test.sh and run this command on path "/home/tommy/use-a-example", such script only throw out home tommy, use-a-example is not in the out.

Comment: Sry, my bad it must be  X <= NF, it was missing the last one